# Number of 4 cycles

Tags: graph-theory, graph-minor

Let $C_4$ be a cycle with four vertices. For an arbitrary graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and m edges say $m>n\sqrt n$, how many $C_4$s exist? Is there a lower bound for this?

Comment: Is this [a research-level question in theoretical computer science](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/235#235)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, this is known.  For $d = \Omega(n^{1/2})$ with a sufficiently large implicit constant, any $n$-node graph of average degree $d$ has $\Omega(d^4)$ total $C_4$s.
This is best possible because it's realized by a random graph.

The earliest reference I'm aware of for this is "Cube-Supersaturated Graphs and Related Problems" by Erdos and Simonovits, where it's claimed without proof.  There are many proofs out there, off the top of my head see Lemma 3 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.03164.pdf).